# 3-manifold proof of Grushko's theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

[Grushko's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grushko_theorem) says that given an epimorphism $\phi: F \to G_1 * G_2$ where $F$ is a finitely-generated free group, there exists. subgroups $F_1$ and $F_2$ of $F$ so that $F = F_1 * F_2$ and $\phi(F_i) = G_i$.

I am trying to piece together a proof of the result that was mentioned [in the introduction of a paper by Stallings](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110807493-025/html) that uses ideas from 3-dimensional topology.  Stallings writes:
"An earlier paper by Kneser  [1] shows how to join together spheres in a 3-manifold to obtain  a given  free  product  structure  on the fundamental groups;  this  can  translate  into  a proof  of Grushko's  original theorem."

Here is my guess of how that proof of Grushko's theorem is supposed to go up until where I am stuck: Take some 2-dimensional CW complexes $K_1$ and $K_2$ with $\pi_1(K_i) \cong G_i$ and take the join of these two spaces by attaching an interval to the disjoint union of $K_1$ and $K_2$ with one endpoint attached to the basepoint of $K_1$ and the other to the basepoint of $K_2$.  Take the midpoint of this interval in this new space as the basepoint and denote the space by $K_1 \vee K_2$.  Now, there is some $k$ with $\pi_1(\sharp^k S^1 \times S^2) \cong F$.

Is there now a map $f : \sharp^k S^1 \times S^2 \to K_1 \vee K_2$ such that $\pi_1(f) = \phi$?

If we had such a map, then by mumbling something a transversality to the basepoint (which is a point I never truly understand in my heart of hearts since the codomain is not a manifold, so if anyone knows a nice way to think of that, I'd love to hear it), then $f^{-1}(*)$ is a bunch of embedded surfaces in $\sharp^k S^1 \times S^2$.  We can then homotope $f$ so that $f^{-1}(*)$ is a bunch of embedded spheres (by compressing the surfaces along disks) and then we can homotope $f$ again to make $f^{-1}(*)$ just a single sphere (by combining the spheres along arcs like Kneser).  From this, Grushko's result follows.

Is this what Stallings had in mind?  If so, how do I prove that $f$ exists?  If not, what did he have in mind?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: Instead of join, connect $K_1, K_2$ by an interval and then take the preimage of a generic point if that interval under a simplicial map of your 3-manifold. This should be in the paper of Scott and Wall.

Comment: It just occurred to me (while reading a bit further in Stallings' paper) that he probably had in mind first killing off the higher homotopy groups of $K_1$ and $K_2$ first, and then proceeding as I said.  This ensures that the aforementioned map $f$ actually exists, since the wedge of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is again an Eilenberg-MacLane space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I think I am being really thick with this, but then don't I just get the preimage to be subsimplical complex?  For what I outlined above I was always thinking of it as a submanifold.  Scott and Wall indeed give a fun topological proof of Gruschko's theorem using a very similar setup, but it doesn't involve this same 3-dimensional manifold-topology flair.

Comment: I would do this with # S^1x D^2 instead of S^2 since a handlebody is irreducible. Transversality is purely local, so you can do it for the midpoint of an interval connecting K(π,1)’s instead of using a strict wedge. Then do compressions and boundary compressions to get down to the preimage being a collection of embedded disks.